# vb.net problems with STAThread() Error: invalidOperationException

Tags: vb.net, sta

I want to make the function "createFolder" faster (or at least not blocking my main thread), by adding a new callback to my threadpool.

I marked the main function with the STAThread() and the exception tells me to mark my main function with the STAThread().

I'm open to any tips!

Answer (score 2):

You have placed the `STAThread` attribute on the wrong method: it needs to be the method that the form is started from, not the method you are executing.

In many cases, your application will have a `Sub Main` and this is what needs to be decorated with the `STAThread` attribute. An example from MSDN:

```
Public Class MyForm
   Inherits Form

   Public Sub New()
      Me.Text = "Hello World!" 
   End Sub 'New 

   <STAThread()> _
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Dim aform As New MyForm()
      Application.Run(aform)
   End Sub 

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't have a main sub.
I have a Form, which imports my ftp class which is containing the createFolder function. I marked the function in my form (which calls the ftp.createFolder() function) with stathread() and it doesn't work. Also tried that with marking the form load handler, same result.

Comment: May I should go some steps back and ask: "How to avoid a blocked Form Thread because of ftp Methods?" At the momement I use a ThreadPool, may someone knows a better solutin?

Comment: @MaBi it seems like you're looking for a way to perform lengthy operations on a background thread in order to prevent the UI from blocking. Since you're building a winforms application you should have a look at the BackgroundWorker component, which simplifies this task. Do a search for BackgroundWorker on Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=backgroundworker%20vb.net